# How to verify call of function factory returning a mock?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq, func

The system under test (Sut) takes the two arguments `Func<IFoo>` and `IBar`. Inside `Sut` an object of `IFoo` is instantiated and then both `foo` and `_bar` are called.

```
public class Sut : ISut
{
    readonly Func<IFoo> _fooFactory;
    IBar _bar;
    
    public Sut(Func<IFoo> fooFactory, IBar bar)
    {
        _fooFactory = fooFactory;
        _bar = bar;
    }
    
    public SutMethod()
    {
        foo = _fooFactory();
        foo.fooMethod();
        
        _bar.barMethod();
    }
}
```

Testing the call of `_bar` is then done by using its mock `barMock`. But how do I test `foo`? How can I very that `foo` is

1. instantiated and
2. called

?

```
public class Test
{
    Func<Func<IFoo>, IBar, ISut> _sutFactory;
    
    public Test(Func<Func<IFoo>, IBar, ISut> sutFactory)
    {
        _sutFactory = sutFactory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestCase()
    {
    
        Func<IFoo> fooFactory = () =>
        {
            var mock => new Mock<IFoo>();
            mock.Setup(x => x.fooMethod();
            return mock.Object;
        }   

        Mock<IBar> barMock = new Mock<IBar>();
        
        sut = _sutFactory(fooFactory, barMock);
        sut.SutMethod();
        
        barMock.Verify(mock => mock.barMethod(), Times.Once());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Has this issue been resolved by the provided answer? If so, remember to accept the provided answer if it resolved the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create the mock outside of the factory delegate so you have access to it for verification

```
public class Test {
    Func<Func<IFoo>, IBar, ISut> _sutFactory;
    
    public Test(Func<Func<IFoo>, IBar, ISut> sutFactory) {
        _sutFactory = sutFactory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestCase() {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IFoo> fooMock = null;
            
        Func<IFoo> fooFactory = () => {
            fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
            return fooMock.Object;
        }

        Mock<IBar> barMock = new Mock<IBar>();
        
        ISut sut = _sutFactory(fooFactory, barMock);

        //Act
        sut.SutMethod();
        
        //Assert
        barMock.Verify(mock => mock.barMethod(), Times.Once());
        // 1. instantiated
        Assert.IsNotNull(fooMock);
        // 2. called
        fooMock.Verify(mock => mock.fooMethod(), Times.Once());
    }   
}
```